# property: private method or private get/set?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

If I want to set my property in a Class private, so it should be only possible to use and set this property in this class, what is the better way? This

```
public string Name { private get; private set }
```

or

```
private string Name { get; set }
```

hmmm and there is also

```
private string Name { private get; private set }
```

Comment: Do you want to set the property to private variable of class?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Yes I think so... not sure I get it what you want ^^

Comment: @Sila i have added my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Please try to compile first. The question about which one is "better" will follow after the question of which one is "compileable" in the first place.

Comment: All of the examples miss a semicolon `;` after the `set`. But even with that, only the second one is legal (see my answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried compiling your examples? Only the middle one will translate.

If you want to specify extra accessibility level keyword, you can only do it on one of the accessors (getter/setter), and that level of the accessor must be more restrictive than the accessibility of the entire property.

Here you see the rules: [Restricting Accessor Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx)

Comment: yeah you are right. Somehow I cannot compile if if use private get; private set only if I use private for get OR for set

Comment: @silla That is because you are setting the Property with one Access Modifier while setting all possible accessors with a different one. Setting it as public with get and set private negates the public part, so it won't compile. If you set it as private, get and set are automatically private, so no need to set them....

Answer (score 18):

It's worth noting that originally, C# wouldn't let you set different accesses on a getter or setter, so the only possible choices were:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
protected internal string Name { get; set; }
internal string Name { get; set; }
protected string Name { get; set; }
private string Name { get; set; }
```

(For that matter, you couldn't have automatic properties and always had to do the writing to and from a backing field yourself, but we'll ignore that just because we'll have shorter examples that way).

It is often useful to have different accesses for the two, most often a more restrictive setter than getter, and so the likes of

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

was introduced.

Now, by extension of that, it would seem logical enough to allow:

```
public string Name { private get; private set; }
private string Name { private get; private set; }
```

However, what are these two expressing?

The second isn't too bad, it's just needlessly repetitious. Still though, it's quite likely that some confused thinking got us there (most likely an incomplete refactoring). Good code is as much about expressing what you are doing as making a computer do something (if anything, more so), better to have it express clearly.

Hence if you end up with the likes of `{ private get; private set; }` then it'd likely be worth looking at again and thinking about what you really want to say here. Hurrah for it being a compiler error.

The first case is even worse. It says "this property is public, except for the setter that is private, and the getter that is private". That's not an exception, "it's this thing, except for all the time" is no real expression of anything. Doubly hurrah the compiler for not letting us do it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: Without specifying different access on a getter or setter, there's a fifth possibility: `protected internal string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep. I'd half a notion that `protected internal` wasn't in C#1.0 and came in later, but a quick search seems to suggest it was always there.

Comment: The `internal` one is now accidentally `private`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen lol. Sometimes one should just leave well alone.

Comment: nice reading, though might be handy for newbies to tell about the most obvious usage : public string name { get; private set}
simply meaning classes can read this property but the class itself sets it.
which could be by a constructor or the result of methods inside this class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

This is what I think you are wanting to do.

There is no point trying to make the get private when the property is public unless you only want your class to see it. In that situation you should use:

```
private string Name { get; set; }
```

Update: On second read, you definitely want the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The better way depends on what you want:

`public string Name { private get; private set }` The property is `public` but **noone** can read or wrote to it, except class itself. That is completely useless, so use just
`private string Name { get;  set }`.

In general if you view the property like a couple of methods (which actually is)

```
private string get_Name() {  }

private string set_Name(value) {  }
```

The reason of having a possibility to apply that identifiers to a property `get/set` becomes evident, I hope.

Comment: FYI, I'm not the downvoter.  I think you mean `private void set_Name(string value) { }`.

Comment: `public string Name { private get; private set; }` won't compile `Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property or indexer 'Program.Name'`

Answer (score 0):

For a private member, you don't need to define accessors.
Just do this:

```
private string _name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want

```
private string name;

public string Name

{

    get { return name; }

    set { name = value; }

}
```

this would allow you to access `private string Name`.

Answer (score 0):

surely enough,
That is the definition of private classifier in OOP: just allow access within methods and scope of the class that owns such private member. Thus if your aim is to disable anyother means of access to a particular member of a class, claiming it as:

```
private <Type_name> <member_identifier> ;
```

is the simplest and enough to make it such.